# Multiple counts within a query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate

I am new to MongoDB and having issues resolving this problem. This mongoDB code works for each individual case but doesn't work when i include it in a single query. Any ideas.

I get the following error: uncaught exception: error: command failed, "ok" : 0; "errmsg" : no such command: '0'", "code" : 59

```
db.employees.aggregate([$match: {$or: [{salary: {$gt:0, $lt:38000}}]}}, 
{$group: {_id: 0, "count": {$sum: 1}}}]), 
[$match: {$or: [{salary: {$gt:38000, $lt:48000}}]}}, 
{$group: {_id: 38000, "count": {$sum: 1}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe better suitable for your case:

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.emp.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608a5dc78c494a06fe633752"), "saalary" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608a5dcb8c494a06fe633753"), "saalary" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608a5dce8c494a06fe633754"), "saalary" : 1000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608a5dd28c494a06fe633755"), "saalary" : 2000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608a5dd68c494a06fe633756"), "saalary" : 4000 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608a73718c494a06fe633757"), "saalary" : 5000 }
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.emp.aggregate([
{$group:{
_id:{ 
  "$cond":{ if:{$and:[ 
     {"$gt": [ "$saalary", 0 ]} ,
     {"$lt": [ "$saalary", 3800 ]}] },
     then:"below3800",
     else:{ 
         "$cond":{ if:{$and:[ 
                  {"$gt": [ "$saalary", 3800 ]} ,
                  {"$lt": [ "$saalary", 4800 ]}] },
                  then:"between3800-4800",
                  else:"above4800"  
                  }
             }
          }
        }  ,cnt:{$sum:1} 
      } 
     }  
   ])
{ "_id" : "above4800", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "between3800-4800", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "below3800", "cnt" : 4 }
MongoDB Enterprise mongos>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a typo in your `$or` expression:
remember the `$` before `gt` operator.

Comment: beside the typo gt that need to be $gt , if you want to have the two different groups in one query you cannot run it in sequence, you can use $facet to split the  tasks in two streams and join them back after...

Comment: db.employees.aggregate([{facet: {$match: {$or: [{salary: {$gt:0, $lt:38000}}]}}, 
    {$group: {_id: 0, "count": {$sum: 1}}}], 
    [$match: {$or: [{salary: {$gt:38000, $lt:48000}}]}}, 
    {$group: {_id: 38000, "count": {$sum: 1}}}}]) Is this the correct way to use the $faceit functionality